# When migrating, the up and down methods are empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, code-first

I develop projects with layered architecture. I am migrating at the Data Access layer. Up and down methods are empty when doing migration alone. What could be the reason?

These are the codes I mapped.

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext()
        : base("Blog")
    {


    }

    internal DbSet<Article> Article { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Gender> Gender { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Member> Member { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Entities.Task> Task { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ArticleMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GenderMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MemberMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TaskMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

Comment: Take a look in your `__MigrationHistory` table in your database, do you have some `AutomaticMigration` entries in there?

Comment: The database does not exist because the up and down methods are not filled. So there is no __MigrationHistory database.